# Android: LiveData postValue() getting null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, android-jetpack

I am trying to transfer a value from one LiveData (`Repository.getMovieList(editTextContent.value.toString()).value`) to another LiveData (`this.movieList.postValue`) using postValue().

I am observing the movieList and want to change it's value from the Repo depending on different buttons that were clicked but I when it runs, it only gets the `null` value and doesn't wait till the Repo's LiveData gets their value.

**Fragment xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="com.example.movieapp.ui.search.SearchMovieFragmentViewModel" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".ui.search.SearchMovieFragment">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_movie_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={viewmodel.editTextContent}"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="Movie Name" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/search_fragment_search_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Search"
            android:onClick="@{() -> viewmodel.getMovieSearchList()}"/>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/search_movie_fragment_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

**SearchMovieFragment**

```
class SearchMovieFragment : Fragment(), MovieSearchItemViewModel {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = SearchMovieFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var searchMovieFragmentViewModel: SearchMovieFragmentViewModel
    private lateinit var binding: SearchMovieFragmentBinding
    private lateinit var movieRecyclerView: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.search_movie_fragment, container, false)
        searchMovieFragmentViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SearchMovieFragmentViewModel::class.java)
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
        binding.viewmodel = searchMovieFragmentViewModel

        setUpRecyclerView(container!!.context)
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun setUpRecyclerView(context: Context) {
        movieRecyclerView = binding.searchMovieFragmentRecyclerView.apply {
            this.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        }
        val adapter = MovieListAdapter()
        adapter.setCallback(this)
        binding.searchMovieFragmentRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

        searchMovieFragmentViewModel.getMovieListLiveData().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {movieList ->
            adapter.submitList(movieList)
        })
    }

}
```

**SearchMovieViewModel**

```
class SearchMovieFragmentViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val editTextContent = MutableLiveData<String>()
    var movieList: MutableLiveData<List<Movie>> =  MutableLiveData()

    fun getMovieSearchList(){
        this.movieList.postValue(Repository.getMovieList(editTextContent.value.toString()).value)
    }

    fun getTrendingMovies() {
        movieList.postValue(Repository.getTrendingMovies().value)
    }

    fun getMovieDetail(movieId: String): MutableLiveData<Movie> {
        return Repository.getMovieDetail(movieId)
    }

    fun getMovieListLiveData() : LiveData<List<Movie>> {
        return movieList
    } 

    private fun getMovieList(movieSearch: String): MutableLiveData<List<Movie>> = Repository.getMovieList(movieSearch)

}
```

Comment: If Repository.getTrendingMovies() and others are LiveData then Repository.getTrendingMovies().value will return null... You should observe and post when data avaible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are implementing it the wrong way, Instead, using the `MediatorLiveData` will be a good and practical solution as it allows you to observe multiple LiveData objects and select between them based on your preferences (a specific action for example).

This is an example of how to implement it in your case

```kotlin
    val editTextContent = MutableLiveData<String>()

    val finalList = MediatorLiveData<List<Movie>>()

    // Here.. Define all of your LiveData objects
    private val movieList = repository.getMovieList(editTextContent.value.toString())
    private val trendingMovies = repository.getTrendingMovies()
    private val movieDetail = repository.getMovieDetail()

    fun setSelection(selection: String) {
        finalList.addSource(movieList) { result ->
            if (selection == "movieList") {
                result?.let { finalList.value = it }
            }
        }
        finalList.addSource(trendingMovies) { result ->
            if (selection == "trendingMovies") {
                result?.let { finalList.value = it }
            }
        }
        finalList.addSource(movieDetail) { result ->
            if (selection == "movieDetail") {
                result?.let { finalList.value = it }
            }
        }
    }
```

So what you have to do is to only observe the `MediatorLiveData` and then call the `setSelection` function and send the correspondent selection action to it as a parameter and it will switch the observation to another `LiveData`

Comment: Hey, this does seem like something that will help with what I am doing! I made the function but it crashes as when it is called again, it tries to readd the source. Also, for some reason, it adds the values of all the sources to the LiveData.

Comment: `addSource` ensures that only one LiveData is being observed at a time so it doesn't observe all of them together.
Try to test each LiveData object separately by observing it in the `SearchMovieFragment` and ensure that all of them are working correctly before merging them.

Comment: Thank you! This was perfect for my situation!